# Default shell not being selected with useradd

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sudo, useradd

I have a fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed and have tried to create a new user account through `root`. I have changed the `SHELL` line in `/etc/default/useradd` to read as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

(it previously read `/bin/sh`)

Executing `useradd -D` provides the following output:

```
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no
```

I then try to create a user as follows:

```
useradd -m -G sudo -c "David Buckley" david
```

Yet the default shell is still `/bin/sh`. More specifically, the `/etc/passwd` file reads as follows:

```
david:x:1000:1000:David Buckley:/home/david:
```

On a slightly, potentially related note, the new user does not receive sudo access. It is given the groups `david sudo`, and the `/etc/sudoers` file includes the lines (uncommented):

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

What might I be doing wrong to cause this?

Comment: It may just be a copying error, but your "Allow members of group..." configuration line should begin `%sudo` not just `sudo`.

Comment: @meuh Yeah, that was the problem. I think I'd tried to uncomment it out at some point in the night. Thanks for spotting it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oddly enough, this happened to me too yesterday on a server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have no concrete answer as to **why** this happens, but here is a quick solution that worked for me:
Don't use `useradd`, use `adduser` instead!

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `adduser` and  `addgroup`  add  users  and  groups  to the system
>          according to command line options and  configuration  information  in `/etc/adduser.conf`.  They are friendlier front ends to
>          the low level tools like `useradd`, `groupadd`  and  `usermod`  programs,  by  default  choosing Debian policy conformant UID and
>          GID values, creating a home directory with skeletal configuration,  running  a  custom script, and other features.

As for `sudo`, you have to log out that user — and then log back in — for the new group settings to have an effect.

Here's a **[good link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd#345986)** on `useradd` vs `adduser`.

Comment: The user has been logged in and out multiple times ;-). Perhaps the sudo issue is actually an unrelated problem after all.

Comment: @Druckles That's odd. Perhaps it's best to ask a new question regarding this particular issue.

Answer (score 8):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1321854) in Ubuntu's `useradd` (added by a Ubuntu-specific patch). It ignores all the settings specified in `/etc/default/useradd`...

The workaround, as indicated in [maulinglawns' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321235/86440), is to use `adduser` instead, which is the recommended tool for adding non-system users in Debian derivatives.

Comment: WoW : ) ,  and besides, Debian shares this bug with Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It reads `/etc/default/useradd` on my system, and applies the `SHELL` setting in particular.

Comment: yes and I can always repeat this bug both on Ubuntu and Debian . If I run `useradd` withdout `-s /bin/bash` after update `/etc/default/useradd`, then I will need to run `chsh -s /bin/bash` for the new users .

Comment: If you don’t mind, please file a bug (`reportbug passwd`). I can’t reproduce the bug, `useradd` works fine for me (it applies the `SHELL` setting from `/etc/default/useradd`).

Comment: `adduser` works fine for me.  I have found many reports/discussion about this bug of `useradd`, and people just reply that `adduser` is find.. I wonder why and what's the content of your `/etc/default/useradd` , or if you just reload the `SHELL` by configs in `/etc/skel` ?

Comment: `grep SHELL= /etc/default/useradd` shows `SHELL=/bin/bash`, and after running `sudo useradd test`, `grep test /etc/passwd` shows `test:x:1010:1013::/home/test:/bin/bash`. Is that conclusive enough? Other settings in `/etc/default/useradd` work just as well. If you have pointers to reports about this bug *in Debian*, I’d be interested to see them.