# Debian 9 - useradd

Tags: debian, group, useradd

Here is an extract of `/etc/default/useradd`:

```
GROUP=1005
```

Here is an extract of `/etc/login.defs`:

```
USERGROUPS_ENAB no
```

Here is the useradd command I run to create a user:

```
$ sudo useradd test22


$ id -a
uid=1006(test22) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

According to man page of useradd above should give me gid=1005. But it give me the default gid=100.

Why doesn't it give me gid=1005?

Here are additional information:

```
$ sudo useradd -D
GROUP=1005
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no


$ sudo apt-cache policy passwd
passwd:
  Installed: 1:4.4-4.1
  Candidate: 1:4.4-4.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.4-4.1 500
        500 http://debian.lth.se/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Does a group with GID 1005 exist?

Comment: Is `GROUP` reset to 100 later in your `/etc/default/useradd`?

Comment: Yes, GID 1005 exists in /etc/group

Comment: There is only one entry of GROUP in /etc/default/useradd. That is 
GROUP=1005
Therefore I cannot see how it can be reset later on.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use the `-N` flag with `useradd`?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same. That is still the gid=100. Not gid=1005.

Comment: Typically with `useradd` you specify it all... what happens if you use `adduser` instead?

Comment: This is a known bug in _Ubuntu_ (but I haven't seen a mentioning of it on Debian).  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321216/default-shell-not-being-selected-with-useradd  The workaround is to use `adduser`.

Comment: Good to know that it is a bug. 
Is it worthwhile if I report it to Debian developers? If yes, where should I report? (I am new to linux world of programming).

Comment: This does indeed sound like the Ubuntu bug in question, but the Debian package doesn’t have the faulty patch. Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `useradd -D`, and that of `apt-cache policy passwd`?

Comment: Stephen, I added the information you requested.